# What is the best way to add a file to my build output using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

Let's say that I have a git repo. In Azure DevOps I pull the repo, build it and deploy to my Azure Web App service. However, I also want to add a file to the build output that is not in the git repo. What is the best way to do this? Is there a specific task I should use?

Comment: Please check my answer. However, you didn't mention what and where is this file, so I assumed you want to create a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use powershell task to fetch (if this is available over internet) or create a file

```bsh
powershell: |
   New-Item -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Name "testfile1.txt" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
```

this script will create a file in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and if you do this before you publish your artifact and your artifact is in `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` you should achieve what you expected.

I assumed you use YAML pipeline but if not then you just need to copy this script into body of this task:
[image]